# Rewrite query without UNION

Tags: sql

I am reading values from 4 tables

```
select '1' as htl_EventId,  
    'Reading Records' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingRecord_Id) as varchar)  as htl_EventTitle, 
     dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_EndDate,'White' as htl_Colour,'ForestGreen' as htl_TextColour,'This is your Reading  no ' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingRecord_Id) as varchar) as htl_EventDescription,
     'http://google.co.in' as htl_UrlValue
     from Reading_Records where User_Id=@UserID and Reading_Date between 
     convert(date, @StartDate, 103) and convert(date, @EndDate, 103) 
     --order by Start_Date ASC
    --('#' + cast((select ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 900000000 + 100000000) as nvarchar)) as htl_Colour,
    union 

    select '2' as htl_EventId,  
    'Incident Details' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Incident_Id ) as varchar)  as htl_EventTitle, 
     dateadd(dd,01,From_Date) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,coalesce(To_Date,from_Date)) as htl_EndDate,'maroon' as htl_Colour,'Black' as htl_TextColour, 'This is your Incident  no ' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Incident_Id ) as varchar) as htl_EventDescription,
     'http://gmail.co.in' as htl_UrlValue
     from User_Incidents where User_Id=@UserID and From_Date >= 
     convert(date, @StartDate, 103) and To_Date <= convert(date, @EndDate, 103) and status='True'
     --order by From_Date ASC

     union 

     select '3' as htl_EventId,  
    'HealthConditions' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Condition_Id ) as varchar)  as htl_EventTitle, 
     dateadd(dd,01,Start_MonthYear) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,Start_MonthYear) as htl_EndDate,'maroon' as  htl_Colour,'Red' as  htl_TextColour,'This is your HealthCondition  no ' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Condition_Id ) as varchar) as htl_EventDescription,
     'http://facebook.com' as htl_UrlValue
     from User_Health_Condition where User_Id=@UserID and Start_MonthYear between 
     convert(date, @StartDate, 103) and convert(date, @EndDate, 103) and status='True'
     order by 1 ASC
```

Please give any suggestion ? Thank you in advance . I need to add one more query for the above

```
select '1' as htl_EventId, 
 dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_EndDate,DR.Reading_Name as htl_ReadingName
 from Reading_Records RR LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.[Defined_Readings] DR  ON RR.Reading_Id=DR.Reading_Id  where User_Id=@UserID
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to make a single query with out using union .

Answer (score 0):

Use Table Variables http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE 
(
    htl_EventId INT, 
    htl_EventTitle, 
    ...,
    ...
)

INSERT INTO @temp 
select '1' as htl_EventId,  
    'Reading Records' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingRecord_Id) as varchar)  as htl_EventTitle, 
     dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_EndDate,'White' as htl_Colour,'ForestGreen' as htl_TextColour,'This is your Reading  no ' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY ReadingRecord_Id) as varchar) as htl_EventDescription,
     'http://google.co.in' as htl_UrlValue
     from Reading_Records where User_Id=@UserID and Reading_Date between 
     convert(date, @StartDate, 103) and convert(date, @EndDate, 103) 

INSERT INTO @temp
select '2' as htl_EventId,  
    'Incident Details' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Incident_Id ) as varchar)  as htl_EventTitle, 
     dateadd(dd,01,From_Date) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,coalesce(To_Date,from_Date)) as htl_EndDate,'maroon' as htl_Colour,'Black' as htl_TextColour, 'This is your Incident  no ' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Incident_Id ) as varchar) as htl_EventDescription,
     'http://gmail.co.in' as htl_UrlValue
     from User_Incidents where User_Id=@UserID and From_Date >= 
     convert(date, @StartDate, 103) and To_Date <= convert(date, @EndDate, 103) and status='True'

INSERT INTO @temp
select '3' as htl_EventId,  
    'HealthConditions' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Condition_Id ) as varchar)  as htl_EventTitle, 
     dateadd(dd,01,Start_MonthYear) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,Start_MonthYear) as htl_EndDate,'maroon' as  htl_Colour,'Red' as  htl_TextColour,'This is your HealthCondition  no ' + cast(rank() OVER (ORDER BY Condition_Id ) as varchar) as htl_EventDescription,
     'http://facebook.com' as htl_UrlValue
     from User_Health_Condition where User_Id=@UserID and Start_MonthYear between 
     convert(date, @StartDate, 103) and convert(date, @EndDate, 103) and status='True'

INSERT INTO @temp
select '1' as htl_EventId, 
 dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_StartDate ,dateadd(dd,01,Reading_Date) as htl_EndDate,DR.Reading_Name as htl_ReadingName
 from Reading_Records RR LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.[Defined_Readings] DR  ON RR.Reading_Id=DR.Reading_Id  where User_Id=@UserID

SELECT * FROM @temp
```